# How would I save Bukkit's default config without removing the notes?

Tags: java, configuration, save, bukkit

I am using Bukkit API 1.7.9 and I have come across a problem.

I am creating an economy system with a `HashMap`, so obviously to not reset the economy system everytime the server restarts, I need to store it in a file. However, if I store it in the default config, I cannot save it without removing the `#notes`.

Here is the code I am using to save/load the economy system `HashMap`:

```
public static final void saveTokensAmount()
{
    for(String playerName : getTokensMap().keySet())
    {
        main.getConfig().set("tokens." + playerName, getTokensMap().get(playerName));
    }
    main.saveConfig();
}

public static final void loadTokensAmount()
{
    if(!main.getConfig().contains("tokens")) return;
    for(String s : main.getConfig().getConfigurationSection("tokens").getKeys(false))
    {
        setTokensBalance(s, main.getConfig().getInt("tokens." + s));
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but the `main.saveConfig();` removes the `#notes`.

I know `saveDefaultConfig();` saves the notes, but I cannot do that here because the user may have editted other variables I have put inside of it.

I *tried* reloading the config with `reloadConfig();` thinking that it would reload it saving this, but it did not.

My question: How would I save Bukkit's default config without removing the `#notes`?

You may think this question is a duplicate, but the usual answer to this is `saveDefaultConfig();`, which I cannot do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your only option in this case is to create a custom YAML file to store the data (if you want to store this kind of data in YAML format), which is the option that I think you should be going with anyway.

I don't think this kind of player data should be saved in a configuration file. A config file, like the name suggests, is used for initial settings or rules for plugins allowing users more control regarding the way the plugin behaves. A lot of newer developers use the config file to save anything they'd like because it is the only way they know how (and the Bukkit API makes it so easy to do) and/or because it was the first way with which they were introduced to saving information to the disk.

Below is some code to help you get started on creating a custom YAML file that will store players' token amount. You should also use the player's unique ID instead of their name to store their token amount because the names might change in the future.

```
//Assuming you have a HashMap somewhere that stores the values
HashMap<String, Integer> tokens = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//Note that the string is not the player name, but the UUID of the player (as a String)
```

I would create the tokens.yml file in your onEnable() method and create a method for easy access to the file. Here is the saveTokensAmount() method (tested, seems to work).

```
void saveTokensAmount() {
    File tokenFile = getTokenFile(); //Get the file (make sure it exists)
    FileConfiguration fileConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(tokenFile); //Load configuration
    for (String id : tokens.keySet()) {
        fileConfig.createSection(id); //Create a section
        fileConfig.set(id, tokens.get(id)); //Set the value
    }
    try {
        fileConfig.save(tokenFile); //Save the file
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //Handle error
    }
}
//Not sure if creating new sections is the most efficient way of storing this data in a YAML file
```

And here is the loadTokensAmount() method:

```
void loadTokensAmount() {
    File tokenFile = getTokenFile(); //Make sure it exists
    FileConfiguration fileConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(tokenFile); //Load configuration
    try {
        fileConfig.load(tokenFile); //Load contents of file
        for (String id : fileConfig.getKeys(false)) { //Get the keys
            tokens.put(id, fileConfig.getInt(id)); //Add values to map
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();;
    }
}
```

To enter initial info for the player, for example when joining the server (you could also write to the file):

```
tokens.put(player.getUniqueId().toString(), amount);
```

Eventually this list/file might get too big to the point where you might want to use a better database. You might also want to store the token amounts in the map/memory only for players that are currently online. Hope this helps!